# Retrieve coordinates on tap and log using NSLog

Tags: cocoa-touch, mapkit

I am using the iOS 6 mapkit and I need to retrieve the coordinates where I tap and log them in NSLog so I can see them. Could someone give me a idiots guide on how to do this? I have looked at many posts but have not found a single one that works.

Thanks in advance,

Ethan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a map view hooked up to a suitable property like this:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
...
@synthesize mapView;
```

You can put this into `viewDidLoad:`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

And then add this function to your controller:

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [mapView convertPoint:[sender locationInView:mapView] toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
    NSLog(@"Map touched %f, %f.", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
}
```

This is all using ARC by the way.